# Is its possible to pass integer value as method arguments in C# console app

Tags: c#, console

In my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

}
```

what i want pass integer value in method args

```
static void Main(int? args)
{

}
```

Comment: Nope. You will need to convert or use one of the many command-line-parser libraries to handle the conversion for you.

Comment: >Ahem, what is the purpose of the ASP.NET tag here?

Comment: where you find asp.net tag ? @Steve

Comment: Has been removed from your tag list. See the edit revision.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't - you can only accept strings. However, you can then parse those strings as integers. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] intArgs = args.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    // ...
}
```

Note that this will throw an exception if any of the arguments isn't actually an integer. If you want a more user-friendly message, you'll need to use `int.TryParse` instead, e.g.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] intArgs = new int[args.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(args[i], out intArgs[i]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"All parameters must be integers. Could not convert {args[i]}");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use console, when you type '123' it is string 123 not integer value 123.
So static void `Main (int[] args)` is not an option.

Check MSDN documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t(VS.71).aspx

However you can parse strings to int.
For instance:

```
var intValue = int.Parse(args[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I Hope that's not possible but you can Get value as string array as you are already getting, and parse them to get required integer.

```
public static int[] intArgs;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     intArgs = args.Select(x=> int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
}
```